# Finding $|E|$, where $E$ is the Splitting Field of $x^8-1$ over a Field of $4$ Elements.

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, factoring, splitting-field

This is my attempt to find $\vert E \vert$, which is the order of the field $E$. If I am on the wrong track, please guide me to a technique that will work with more general fields and polynomials.

We have a field $F$ with $4$ elements (which we can denote by $0,1,1+1,1+1+1)$. Factorization:
$$x^8-1=(x^4+1)(x^4-1)=(x^2+1)(x^2-1)(x^4+1)\\=(x+1)(x-1)(x^2+1)(x^4+1)$$ so if we adjoin $i$ to $F$ ($x^2+1$ will factor) we have $$x^8-1=(x+1)(x-1)(x+i)(x-i)(x^4+1)$$ and if we adjoin $\sqrt 2$ then $x^4+1$ will factor into $(x^2 + \sqrt 2 x+1)(x^2 - \sqrt 2 x + 1)$. So $E=F(i,\sqrt 2)$. Thus, $E$ has $4^3=64$ elements.

Is my work correct? In general, if I don't know the elements of my field, how can I determine whether new elements have to be added into my field in order to factorize? In this case, how do we know $i, \sqrt 2\not \in F$?

Comment: Note that $1+1=0$.

Comment: It is well-known that there is no $i$ in *team*, but there is also no $i$ in characteristic $2$ ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Good one. I goofed up from the start by not considering the characteristic of $F$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the characteristic is $2$, we have$$x^8-1=(x^4-1)^2=(x^2-1)^4=(x-1)^8.$$This should make everything a lot easier.